# How to add an additional AuthenticationProvider without using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security

Prior to Spring Security 5.7 it was possible to add additional `AuthenticationProviders` to the global `AuthenticationManager` this way:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

}
```

With Spring Security 5.7 the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated.

**Question**: ho should i migrate this code to solve the deprecation?

When i try to register the additional `AuthenticationProvider` as `@Bean`, the autocreated authentication provider for username/password based authentication gets replaced, leading to

```
No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

I read the blog post https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter but found no hints about adding additional authentication providers to the global `AuthenticationManager`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a single `AuthenticationProvider` you can register it as a bean and it will be picked up by Spring Security:

```java
@Bean
public CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
}
```

Alternatively, you can add additional `AuthenticationProvider`s in the `HttpSecurity` configuration:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent automatic pickup of an `AuthenticationProvider` registered as `@Bean`?

Comment: I found no solution for my last inquiry. So i went down the road show by Eleftheria and now avoid registering my `CustomAuthenticationProvider` as `@Bean`.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions. However, nothing worked. I tested it with spring 2.7.1 and 2.7.2. I added log messages to my custom authentification provider. It is not invoked for a request that requires authentication. This is my config: 
`.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/api/v1/noauth1", "/api/v1/noauth2").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())`

I can access the "noauth2" urls just fine, but get a 401 if I try to access anything else.

Comment: This isn't working for me with Spring Boot 2.7.17.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your configuration class with **@EnableGlobalAuthentication** and will be able to configure a global instance of AuthenticationManagerBuilder:

```
   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
      auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
   }
```

Please see the related documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/EnableGlobalAuthentication.html

Comment: I can confirm that configuration of the global `AuthenticationManager` is possible this way. But builtin providers, like `DaoAuthenticationProvider` configured by e.g. `formLogin()`  get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a custom user details service and I also use an additional custom authentication provider. One is for actual users and the custom provider is for automated devices.

This is my code with the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
  
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    ...

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        var encoder = passwordEncoder();
        customAuthenticationProvider.encoder(encoder);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    ...
}
```

This is my code without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    ...

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
  
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    ...

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        var encoder = passwordEncoder();
        customAuthenticationProvider.encoder(encoder);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    ...

}
```

note: you might need to set spring.main.allow-circular-references to true in your properties file for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem when I want to add an custom AuthenticationProvider using Spring Security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Here is what I did.

Code with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    }
```

Code without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SecurityConfiguration { 
    
        ...

        @Autowired
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        void registerProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
           auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }
    }
```

Note: @EnableGlobalAuthentication and registerProvider().

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried that, but the builtin `DaoAuthenticationProvider` still got replaced. I want to add an *additional* authentication provider.